# Specify setup time dependency with `--global-option` for a python package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to package a python library that has setup-time (and also run-time) dependencies: it `import`s the modules so that the modules can inform the setup process of the location of some provided C headers:

```
from distutils.extension import Extension
from pybedtools.helpers import get_includes as pybedtools_get_includes
from pysam import get_include as pysam_get_include
# [...]
extensions = [
    Extension(
        "bam25prime.libcollapsesam", ["bam25prime/libcollapsesam.pyx"],
        include_dirs=pysam_get_include()),
    Extension(
        "bam25prime.libcollapsebed", ["bam25prime/libcollapsebed.pyx"],
        include_dirs=pybedtools_get_includes(),
        language="c++"),
    ]
# [...]
```

However, one of the dependencies (`pybedtools`) needs to be installed with a specific `--global-option` pip option (see at the end of the post what happens when the option is not provided).

If I understand correctly, the currently up-to-date way to automatically have some dependencies available before `setup.py` is used is to indicate them in the `[build-system]` section of a `pyproject.toml` file.

I tried the following `pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "pysam",
    "pybedtools @ git+https://github.com/blaiseli/pybedtools.git@fix_missing_headers --global-option='cythonize'",
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

(By the way, it took me quite some time to figure out how to specify the `build-backend`, the documentation is not easily discoverable.)

However, this generates the following error upon `pip install`:

```
  ERROR: Invalid requirement: "pybedtools @ git+https://github.com/blaiseli/pybedtools.git@fix_missing_headers --global-option='cythonize'"
  Hint: It looks like a path. File 'pybedtools @ git+https://github.com/blaiseli/pybedtools.git@fix_missing_headers --global-option='cythonize'' does not exist.
```

**How can I correctly specify options for dependencies** ?

If I simply specify the package and its URL (`"pybedtools @ git+https://github.com/blaiseli/pybedtools.git@fix_missing_headers`), the install fails as follows:

```
    Exception:
                            Cython-generated file 'pybedtools/cbedtools.cpp' not found.

                            Please install Cython and run

                                python setup.py cythonize
```

It was while trying to tackle the above error that I found out about the `--global-option` pip option.
I can manually run `pip install --global-option="cythonize" git+https://github.com/blaiseli/pybedtools.git@fix_missing_headers`, and the install works, provided the dependencies of that package are already installed, otherwise their install fails because of an unrecognized `"cythonize"` option (which is [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58379992/1878788)...).

Note that this option is only needed when installing "from source" (for instance when installing from a fork on github, as is my case here).

Comment: To better understand the issue, where does that _setuptools_ `cythonize` option come from?

Comment: The `cythonize` option is meant to be handled by the `setup.py` script of the dependency of my package: https://github.com/daler/pybedtools/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: To me it definitely looks like a command and not an option, so the alias might be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing as in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58379992/1878788), I suspect `cythonize` is a *setuptools* command and not a *global option*.

If it's indeed the case, then you would be better off setting an *alias* in your `setup.cfg`. If you run `python setup.py alias install cythonize install`, this should add the following to your `setup.cfg`:

```
[aliases]
install = cythonize install
```

When running `pip install` later, *pip* will honor this alias and the `cythonize` command will be executed right before the `install` command.