# How to install separately a python package and its dependencies using pip in order to allow separated pip options?

Tags: python, pip

I have (a fork of) a python package that needs an extra option in order to be installed. I found out that this could be done using the `--global-option` option of pip:

```
pip install --global-option="cythonize" git+https://github.com/blaiseli/pybedtools.git@fix_missing_headers
```

However, this option makes the installation of this package's dependencies fail, because it also applies to them, and is not recognized.

**How can I separately install the dependencies first?**

Something like `pip install --only-deps <some package>` does not seem to exist.

---

#### Edit

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58385234/1878788), I tried setting up an alias in my fork of the package, in order to have the `cythonize` command run before install:

```
$ cat setup.cfg 
[wheel]
universal = 1
[nosetests]
detailed-errors = 1
doctest-extension = .pyx .py
[aliases]
install = cythonize install
```

Strangely, the `cythonize` command is handled correctly:

```
$ python3.7 setup.py cythonize
running cythonize
Compiling pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx because it changed.
Compiling pybedtools/featurefuncs.pyx because it changed.
[1/2] Cythonizing pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /home/bli/src/pybedtools/pybedtools/cbedtools.pxd
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
[2/2] Cythonizing pybedtools/featurefuncs.pyx
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /home/bli/src/pybedtools/pybedtools/featurefuncs.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
```

But it is not recognized when it is part of an alias:

```
$ python3.7 setup.py install
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'cythonize'
```

Comment: Looks like your misusing the `--global-option`, but if it works for you, good. Indeed `cythonize` does not seem to be a setuptools _global option_, it looks more like a setuptools command that you want to run before the `install` command. Have you tried setting an *alias* in your `setup.cfg `instead? `python setup.py alias install cythonize install`

Answer (score 0):

Same thing as in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58379905/11138259), I suspect `cythonize` is a *setuptools* command and not a *global option*.

If it's indeed the case, then you would be better off setting an *alias* in your `setup.cfg`. If you run `python setup.py alias install cythonize install`, this should add the following to your `setup.cfg`:

```
[aliases]
install = cythonize install
```

When running `pip install` later, *pip* will honor this alias and the `cythonize` command will be executed right before the `install` command.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what is actually a "global option" in the sense of the `--global-option` option of pip. In my case, `cythonize` is indeed an option meant to be passed to `setup.py`. It seems to me that what you propose is a change to the python package I'm trying to install (I can try it in my fork of that package, but it would be better if the official maintainer of the package did it).

Comment: The command line for `setup.py` is `python setup.py [global options] command [command options]`. For example `python setup.py -q install -O2`. `pip --global-options` configures that global options for `setup.py`.

Comment: Definitely try the alias in your fork, and if it indeed adds value, then suggest the change to the maintainers of the upstream project.

Comment: I tried to add the lines you suggest in the `setup.cfg` of my fork of that package (https://github.com/blaiseli/pybedtools/blob/auto_cythonize/setup.cfg), but it doesn't seem to work when I run `pip install git+https://github.com/blaiseli/pybedtools.git@auto_cythonize` I get an `error: invalid command 'cythonize'`

Comment: @phd From your comment I understand that `cythonize` should be a `command` for `setup.py`, not a `global option` nor a `command option`. What is the correct way to tell pip to run another command before `install`?

Comment: I'm not sure it is. [Docs](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html#building-a-cython-module-using-distutils) say the command is `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and `cythonize` is a keyword in `setup.py`.

Comment: @phd the `cythonize` setuptools command comes from pybedtools not from cython.

Comment: The custom setuptools command `cythonize` is only added when it is found in `sys.argv`, which is very confusing... You probably can fix this in your fork. https://github.com/blaiseli/pybedtools/blob/c6f9123b28f78dd34eef6f1314de45cecbcf71fc/setup.py#L223

Comment: @sinoroc I tried something, but it does not seem to work. I think this is beyond my current abilities. Much simpler would be to have a way to install dependencies only first, then the package itself using `--global-option="cythonize"`. This may not be clean, but works with the current state of the package.

Comment: Yes I have seen your [change](https://github.com/blaiseli/pybedtools/commit/b5c7466a0927b4be36b9285e199d890fd1f3454a). I would have bet this would have worked. Too bad, this would have been much cleaner indeed.

Answer (score 0):

*pip* somewhat supports `requirements.txt` files with inline options. So you could go with a `requirements.txt` like this:

```
# ...
cython
git+https://github.com/blaiseli/pybedtools.git@fix_missing_headers --global-option="cythonize"
# ...
```

And install like this:

`pip install --requirement requirements.txt`

I say *somewhat* because it still seems to have (apparently non damaging) effects on the installation of the other requirements. In particular it seems to disable wheels for the other requirements and dependencies, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The issue related to globally disabling wheels is [pypa/pip#4118](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4118).

Comment: @bli does that help solving your issue?